# How to step through VBA code behind a form? VBA error 2186: This property isn't available in Design view

Tags: vba, ms-access

I can run a macro under forms, but when I look at the code behind the form, I am not able to step through it all.

I hit the line

```vb
Dat = [Forms]![frmMenu]![dtmDate]
```

and get the error:
[image]

Is there a way to resolve this so I can continue to test each step of the macro?

I opened the code with ALT + F11.

I am trying to pinpoint the queries which cause the macro to take so long to run.

Comment: get out of design view?

Comment: Is that MSAccess vba code? Is the form open (actually really open ... not just in design mode but in actual use?). The most common problem here is that the form isn't there at runtime.

Comment: When I open the form in the background, it seems to work.  I think the form in the background needed to be in it's default form view instead of design view

Comment: You cannot pull data from a control that doesn't exist. If the form is closed, like design time is, then the control is null. It's like trying to test the accelerator pedal of a car that is off. The car won't go vroom unless you start it first before stepping on the pedal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hit f5 to run + debug code in a form. You can do this for a standard code module, but not for what we call a class module.

If you wish to debug/step code in a form? Launch the form (normal view). Then go to the code behind, say a button click, and now you can set a break-point.

So, single step, or debug of forms code requires you FIRST load the form as normal. (you can't thus use f5 to run such code). But, you CAN debug as per above.